# How to apply css before child class

Tags: html, css, parent-child, child-process

i want to apply css before p tag td. other td should be not effected

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
  <td>heading</td>
    <td>some data</td>
      <td><p class="may-class">Date</p></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: could you clarify with an example? what should be the result?

Comment: Hi friend, do you have a problem we can help you with?

Comment: I want add class in previous element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `td` with the `p-class` is always the only and last element of the `tr` you can use `:last-child` css styling.

Like:

```
tr td:last-child {
    color:red;
}
```

EDIT:
It doesnt work with CSS. CSS cant get the parent of an element. Use `jQuery/javascript` instead:

```
jQuery('.may-class').parent().addClass('someClass');
```

Comment: I have  more td. i want apply only befor p tag td

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
  <td>heading</td>
    <td>some data</td>
      <td><p class="may-class">Date</p></td>
  <td>some data</td>
  <td>some data</td>
 </tr>
</table>

Comment: Than you have to use the javascript/jquery approach and add a class to the parent like shown in my edit.

Comment: can it will possible to achieve this using css

Comment: Like DMTintner wrote: It is not possible to do this with CSS!. (Read his links (i recommend the second one) If you want to add a class to the td before your p you need `javascript` or `jQuery`

Answer (score 2):

What it sounds like you are looking for is a parent selector, which CSS doesn't contain (yet...)
http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

What I would do is apply a class to the td that you want to style. If you can't access the HTML than maybe you can style the p tag inside of the td with a direct child selector:

```
td > p { ... }
```

Refer to this question for ways to style it using Javascript:
[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: No luck

<style>

td > p.my-class { color:red}


</style>



<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
  <td>heading</td>
    <td>some data</td>
      <td> want to red color on this <p class="my-class">Date</p></td>
 </tr>
</table>